# I got stung by bees in animal crossing new leaf

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I got stung by bees in animal crossing new leaf and None of the people have offered medicine. I don't know how to upgrade nookling junction. If anyone has gotten medicine from the following please tell me:

Walt, Bruce, Pietro, Alice, Derwin, Bluebear, Frobert, or Diana.

Where am I supposed to get the medicine for my bee stings?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy medicine at the T&T Mart, Super and Imperium. See [this list](http://bidoofcrossing.tumblr.com/post/51874258260/animal-crossing-new-leaf-nookling-stores) for medicine availability and opening times.

Comment: I don't have t&t mart yet

Comment: The weird thing is it has been more than seven days and I do have a house.